# How can I parse Date format in Java with different locale

Tags: java, date

I am facing issue with Date.parse() method for non-English locale with English OS. 
I am using the Date.parse() method to parse the entered value of date. It would be different for different locales. Here are some examples.
03-Feb-2016 00:00  English
01.Feb.2016 00:00  Germany
2016-2-01 00:00    Japanese

So for German locale, above string (01.Feb.2016 00:00) pass to the parse()

```
            try
            {
                Date.parse( value );
            }
            catch( IllegalArgumentException e )
            {
                valid_value= false;
            }
```

where value is "01.Feb.2016 00:00" then it goes to catch block.
Please help me on how can I validate the value or convert the value acceptable by English locale.

Comment: you  should have DateFormat.getDateInstance(int style, Locale locale) , you can refer to the documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is usually the way to go for all your parsing needs...

Comment: Thanks for reply,
Actually I went through that document and implemented same code but in my case (For German locale) it wasn't accepting the character "e" from "01.Feb.2016 00:00".

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code

```
//Germany local date
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat;
dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,Locale.GERMANY);
dateFormat.format(date);
```

OR

```
 SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.GERMANY);
 simpleDateFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DateFormat.getInstance()` to get a specific instance of formatter for your Locale:

```java
DateFormat format = DateFormat.getInstance(SHORT, locale);
```

Comment: Hi in this case it returns the format as "dd.MM.YY" and not the "dd.mmm.YYYY" for German locale.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, you can choose only from the predefined ones if you do not want to define the format yourself. So SHORT, MEDIUM, LONG, FULL. If neither are what you are looking for, you might have to specify your "custom" format for each Locale you want to support.

Comment: @Jaydeep try MEDIUM instead of SHORT

Comment: maybe this can help new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.GERMANY)

Comment: @Vaseph It would be hard-coded for Germany. I wouldn't be bale to use for other locales.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam The custom would be hard-coded for specific locale right?

Comment: @Jaydeep Yes, unfortunately. See comments about `SimpleDateFormat`. You would have to specify formats for each Locale you want to support, the only thing you still get from the JDK is the translations for day and month for each language. So MMMM would be "Juni" in German, but "June" in English.